# Why is run time affected by a materialized view's name?

Tags: postgresql

We've been trying to run a script in postgreSQL which creates a materialized view. It was taking a ridiculously long time to run and we couldn't work out why. We tried saving it to a different name, and suddenly it took only 5 seconds. What could be the reason for that?

The script we tried to run:

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS wscc_natcap.tmbc_merged_with_biggest_rd cascade;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW wscc_natcap.tmbc_merged_with_biggest_rd AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (m.kwtid)
    m.kwtid,
    m.geom,
    (
        SELECT road_type
        FROM wscc_natcap.openrd_clipped_tmbc AS c
        WHERE ST_Intersects(m.geom, ST_Buffer(c.geom, 200))
        ORDER BY
            CASE
                WHEN c.road_type = 'm' THEN 1
                WHEN c.road_type = 'a_rd' THEN 2
                WHEN c.road_type = 'b_rd' THEN 3
                WHEN c.road_type = 'u' THEN 4
                ELSE NULL -- Assign a higher value to any unexpected road_type
            END
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS biggest_rd
FROM wscc_natcap.tmbc_greenspace AS m
LIMIT 1;
```

We tried it with and without the 'drop view' line, and ensured the mat view didn't already exist.

The name I changed it to was:

```
wscc_natcap.tmbc_merged_with_biggest_rd_kia_test
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Someone or something is/was still using it or attempting a similar operation. Refer to [lock monitoring](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) to see what's holding the lock.

You can reproduce this:

1. Start three concurrent sessions, A, B and C
2. From A:

   ```sql
   create materialized view test as select 1;
   ```

   and commit the operation.
3. From B issue

   ```sql
   begin;
   select * from test;
   ```

   and stay that way, without committing or rolling back.
4. From A, try to drop it:

   ```sql
   drop materialized view if exists test;
   ```

   It will hang because B is still using it.
5. From C, run a [lock monitoring](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) query: it'll show B blocking A. One counter-intuitive thing about the ouput of that is it'll show the current query in B's *transaction*, which might have nothing to do with the table - it's the transaction that's holding on to it, and it's the transaction that needs to be concluded, not just the most recent statement inside it.

The same would happen if B was in the process of creating or dropping it at the same time as A tried to do the same. It's best to wait for the operation to finish or request it to finish. If that's not an option, you can use [`pg_cancel_backend()` or `pg_terminate_backend()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL).